# How to ignore a varying number of starting 0s in a SQL column for group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am using the following query to find repeated numbers in my table:

```
SELECT 
    c.code,
    COUNT(c.code) 
FROM cards c
group by c.code
HAVING COUNT(c.code)>1;
```

But the column code has varying numbers of 0s before the numbers, as an example:

```
0001897
001897
01897
1897
```

How could I make that query ignore all 0s before the numbers to consider all of the above as repeated (the same row in a group by)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [TRIM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function with `LEADING '0'`

```
SELECT 
    TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM c.code),
    COUNT(c.code) 
FROM cards c
group by TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM c.code)
HAVING COUNT(c.code)>1;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3a1a86b0efec9f994808fa068846bd4c)